# assembly code for C++ scoped static initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, assembly, static-variables

i read some old articles about the local scoped static variable initialzation order problem from

[C++ scoped static initialization is not thread-safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/08/85901.aspx) back in 2004, and

[Function Static Variables in Multi-Threaded Environments](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/assemblylanguage/article.php/c12897/Function-Static-Variables-in-MultiThreaded-Environments.htm) in 2006.

then I start to produce an example and check my compiler, gcc 4.4.7

```
int calcSomething(){}

void foo(){
    static int x = calcSomething();
}

int main(){
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

the result from objdump shows:

```
000000000040061a <_Z3foov>:
  40061a:   55                      push   %rbp
  40061b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40061e:   b8 d0 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600ad0,%eax
  400623:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%rax),%eax
  400626:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  400628:   75 28                   jne    400652 <_Z3foov+0x38>
  40062a:   bf d0 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600ad0,%edi
  40062f:   e8 bc fe ff ff          callq  4004f0 <__cxa_guard_acquire@plt>
  400634:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  400636:   0f 95 c0                setne  %al
  400639:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  40063b:   74 15                   je     400652 <_Z3foov+0x38>
  40063d:   e8 d2 ff ff ff          callq  400614 <_Z13calcSomethingv>
  400642:   89 05 90 04 20 00       mov    %eax,0x200490(%rip)        # 600ad8 <_ZZ3foovE1x>
  400648:   bf d0 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600ad0,%edi
  40064d:   e8 be fe ff ff          callq  400510 <__cxa_guard_release@plt>
  400652:   c9                      leaveq 
  400653:   c3                      retq
```

unfortunately, my knowledge of asssmbly code is so limited that I cannot tell what compiler does here. Can anyone shed me some light, what this assembly code do? and is it still not thread-safe? I really appreciate some "pseudo code" showing what gcc is doing here.

EDIT-1:
as Jerry commented, I enabled optimization with O2, the assembly code is:

```
0000000000400620 <_Z3foov>:
  400620:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400624:   80 3d 85 04 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x200485(%rip)        # 600ab0 <_ZGVZ3foovE1x>
  40062b:   74 0b                   je     400638 <_Z3foov+0x18>
  40062d:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400631:   c3                      retq   
  400632:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400638:   bf b0 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600ab0,%edi
  40063d:   e8 9e fe ff ff          callq  4004e0 <__cxa_guard_acquire@plt>
  400642:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  400644:   74 e7                   je     40062d <_Z3foov+0xd>
  400646:   c7 05 68 04 20 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x200468(%rip)        # 600ab8 <_ZZ3foovE1x>
  40064d:   00 00 00 
  400650:   bf b0 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600ab0,%edi
  400655:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400659:   e9 a2 fe ff ff          jmpq   400500 <__cxa_guard_release@plt>
  40065e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

Comment: It looks like you've compiled without optimization, which leads to some crappy code, but at least at first glance, it looks like it's intended to be thread safe--the `__cxa_guard_acquire` looks like it's acquiring a mutex, so only one thread will ever call `calcSomething`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  In pseudocode (for the un-optimized case) it's something like:

```
if (flag_val() != 0) goto done;
if (guard_acquire() != 0) goto done;
x = calcSomething();
guard_release_and_set_flag();
// Note releasing the guard lock causes later 
// calls to flag_val() to return non-zero.
done: return
```

The `flag_val()` is really a non-blocking check, apparently for efficiency to avoid calling the `acquire` primitive unless necessary. The flag must be set by `guard_release` as shown.  The `acquire` seems to be the synchronized call to grab the lock.  Only one thread will get a true value back and perform the initialization.  After it releases the lock, the non-zero flag prevents any further touches of the lock.

Another interesting tidbit is that the guard data structure is 8 bytes away from the value of `x` itself in static memory.

Those familiar with the singleton pattern in languages with built-in threads e.g. Java will recognize this!

**Addition**

A bit more time now, so in a bit more detail:

```
000000000040061a <_Z3foov>:

  ; Prepare to access stack variables (never used in un-optimized code).
  40061a:   55                      push   %rbp
  40061b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp

  ; Test a byte 8 away from the static int x. This is apparently an "initialized" flag.
  40061e:   b8 d0 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600ad0,%eax
  400623:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%rax),%eax
  400626:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al

  ; Goto the end of the function if the byte was no-zero.
  400628:   75 28                   jne    400652 <_Z3foov+0x38>

  ; Load the same byte address in di: the argument for the call to 
  ; acquire the guard lock. 
  40062a:   bf d0 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600ad0,%edi
  40062f:   e8 bc fe ff ff          callq  4004f0 <__cxa_guard_acquire@plt>

  ; Test the return value. Goto end of function if not zero (non-optimized code).
  400634:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  400636:   0f 95 c0                setne  %al
  400639:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  40063b:   74 15                   je     400652 <_Z3foov+0x38>

  ; Call the user's initialization function and move result into x.
  40063d:   e8 d2 ff ff ff          callq  400614 <_Z13calcSomethingv>
  400642:   89 05 90 04 20 00       mov    %eax,0x200490(%rip)        # 600ad8 <_ZZ3foovE1x>

  ; Load the guard byte's address again and call the release routine.
  ; This must set the flag to non-zero.
  400648:   bf d0 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600ad0,%edi
  40064d:   e8 be fe ff ff          callq  400510 <__cxa_guard_release@plt>

  ; Restore state and return.
  400652:   c9                      leaveq 
  400653:   c3                      retq
```

[This listing](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxxabi/trunk/src/cxa_guard.cpp), although for the LLVM compiler rather than g++ (are you running OS X? OS X aliases g++ to LLVM), agrees with the guesswork above.  The `set_initialized` routine is setting a flag value in `guard_release`.

Comment: Your pseudo code can't be entirely accurate, because clearly you have to set `guard_val` somewhere to != 0. From the assembly (ugh AT&T syntax) I guess this is actually done in `guard_release` which gets the location passed in `edi`. Which seems strange but since we don't write to `600ab0` anywhere in the function this seems the only logical explanation (it actually seems we pass it to both acquire and release, but clearly it should only be set after the release).

Comment: Fair point. I'm assuming it's implicit in acquiring the lock.  I'll fiddle with the text.

Comment: hi, Gene, thanks for your detailed answer. I do learn a lot from it. I assume the thread will be preempted or blocked at guard_acquire(), which guarantees that initialization happenes only once. but regarding guard_val(), from your pseudocode, the thread which gets non-zero value will return. isn't it the problem that it will return/use/proceed with non-initialized value. Or is this thread preempted or blocked also at guard_val()? I cannot see how this can prevent non-initialized case occuring.

Comment: @pepero  Thanks. You are right! There must be a flag independent of the lock value. It must be `guard_release` that sets the flag. I edited the answer. I looked around the gcc c++ library source but do not have time to find the acquire and release primitive code.  Would be interesting to look at.